# Send IR success but doesn't turn on the TV

Tags: infrared

My circuit is simple:

IR sensor (from left to right): PIN 11, GND, 5V
IR transmitter: GND, PIN 1 (via resistor). (BTW: all of the tutorials I read says that the PIN should be 3 but from some reason it sends only when it connected to PIN 1. How do I know? because I can "see" the light via the mobile's camera like the image below)

[image]

I'm trying to "record" an IR signal and sent it. The code come from gits I found:

```
#include <IRremote.h>

int RECV_PIN = 11;

IRrecv irrecv(RECV_PIN);
IRsend irsend;

boolean recording = true;
decode_results results;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  irrecv.enableIRIn(); // Start the receiver
}

void loop() {
  if (recording) {
    if (irrecv.decode(&results)) {
      Serial.println("IR code recorded!");
      //irrecv.resume(); // Receive the next value
      Serial.print("Recorded ");
      Serial.print(results.rawlen);
      Serial.println(" intervals.");
      recording = false;
    }
  } else {
    // replay mode
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      Serial.println("Sending recorded IR signal!");     
      irsend.sendRaw((unsigned int*) results.rawbuf, results.rawlen, 38);  
      delay(40);
    }
    delay(2000);
  }
}
```

https://gist.github.com/jeje/3027236

Like you can see in the image, the signal is sent but it does nothing to the TV (I record the TV's remote of course)

Comment: Are you sure your remote runs at 38kHz?

Comment: @Majenko thanks! I'm not. I thought that it's kind of generic. How can I know? Can I print it somehow?

Comment: You can only really know by connecting a photodiode up to an oscilloscope and examining the actual waveform directly.

Comment: Can I use the arduino to exam it?

Comment: pin 1 is Serial TX. on Uno. what is your board?

Comment: Pin 3 is way more sensible on an Arduino Uno/Nano because it can do PWM. The library needs to pulse out a 38kHz PWM modulated waveform at a PWM capable pin. The reason you are able to see the infrered LED light up at pin 1 is because that is the TX of your UART at 9600 bits per second, way slower than the IR PWM. You **must** use the pins outlined in https://github.com/z3t0/Arduino-IRremote

Comment: Also double check the contents of `results.rawbuf` becore `sendRaw`, e.g. by serially outputting every byte. Maybe you're sending something different than what you want.

Comment: I believe, I see an receiver IC on your board. If it is one for 38kHz modulated IR signal and you receive pulses from it, then your remote definitely works with 38kHz

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt the thing is I can't see the light in pin 3 and also, it doesn't work. I can see the light in all of the remotes I have. Why it's different in the arduino?

Comment: @chrisl I don't know what is receiver IC. Also, why do you think it's not working?

Comment: By the way, my arduino is uno r3 based on atmega328p-pu. And I can't find it in the list of the IR library.

Comment: Try attaching an visible led for debugging. Most remotes the the code multiple times, so that might explain why you can see those codes, but not on your own, is your own is just too short.

Comment: Your Uno R3 belongs to the ATMega328 section of that table, i.e. transmit on Pin 3 (and using Timer2). And you are right, you should see something there on Pin 3. I would exchange the IR LED for a normal red LED and look at in a dark room. You should see a *very* dimm light being emitted. What's the value of your resistor?

Comment: Can you tell us what is your TV model ?
Let me explain why: the freq and codes used in remotes are (almost) normalized. Therefore, by knowing your TV model, you could find the right IR protocol. There are libraries for IR codes in Arduino, if your TV model IR protocol matches one available in arduino IR lib, then you're done.

Comment: I will try to connect regular led to PIN 3. Thanks! I tried 220 and 1k resistors.